# How to know the process speed of task in Hadoop in each time

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

When I run the Hadoop program ,I want to know the speed of it in each time. How I can know the speed ,for example after 10% of job was completed?

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring the progress of Hadoop jobs is of high interest as these are long running jobs ( which sometimes take days to finish). A meaningful progress update is helpful to the user to figure out if the jobs are running properly or it is stuck because of some error deep within the stack of Hadoop.

According to the Hadoop definitive guide,

Measuring the progress of Hadoop jobs can be split in to phases, the Map phase and the Reduce phase (surprise surprise !!!). Measuring the progress of the Map phase is relatively easy. In the beginning the input data is split into chunks and one map task is spawned for each of the chunk. Just monitor how many map phases are done gives a progress update on the Map phase.

Reduce phase is somewhat tricky. There are three phases for a reduce task, namely, Copy, Sort and Reduce. These three phases are used to monitor the progress of the reduce phase. For example if the in a particular reduce task, "reduce" part is half done then we say that this reduce task is 5/6 done. (1/3 copy + 1/3 sort + 1/6 reduce = 5/6).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got your answer,but How I can  see this process? what tools I should install ?thanks

Comment: Hadoop provides a web interface to monitor this purpose. I have written simple shell scripts to extract the required values by scraping the page. I am sure there are some better ways to do it.